# WinHTTP Cannot resolve the host name first time

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, winhttp, winhttprequest

I have a Delphi application that uses WinHTTP. Everything was fine until two weeks back. However, some users started to experience the "Server Name cannot be resolved" error when the application tried to access a remote server for the first time. But it resolves after that. They might get it the next day as well.

I have about 100 users experiencing this. But I have many more users who have no problem. Also, a few users had the error persistently. The drivers/etc/hosts file entry solved the problem for them. What could be the reason?

Here is the basic code:

```
      httpRequest := CoWinHTTPRequest.Create;
      httpRequest.SetTimeouts(60000,60000,60000,60000);   //1 minute for everything
      httpRequest.Open('POST',url,False);


      jsPostRequest.AddPair('email',UserName);
      jsPostRequest.AddPair('password',Password);
      jsPostRequest.AddPair('ttl','8');
      RequestStr := jsPostRequest.ToString;


      httpRequest.SetRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');

      try

        httpRequest.send(RequestStr);

      except on e:Exception do

         ShowMessage(e.message);   //<------------ ERROR       
      end;
```

Update:

I don't have this problem if I use Indy TIdHTTP.

What makes Indy can resolve the DNS but WinHTTP cannot?

Comment: Another possible cause for this and the fact that it is happening only for some users might be their AntiVirus software interfering.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It came out of the blue - but there was no update right before this problem started. Some of them claimed that their auto update is disabled. Is it even remotely possible that this error is a result of a problem in the server which WinHTTP claims that it cannot resolve the name of?

Comment: DNS / name resolution issues can cause this. Lot of possibilities - lack of due care transferring a domain between registrars, out of date / misconfigured name server that doesn't have all the name records for the domain / etc. There are various DNS troubleshooting guides on the web.

Comment: I have updated the question. I just found that the Indy components doesn't have this problem.